# WHS2011: Disk space for Windows doesn't stop to increase

Tags: windows-home-server

I have a WHS2011 and I swapped the main drive because the empty space got low (from 68 GB to 256 GB). On this drive there is only the installation of Windows and a few applications. Again I don't have free space. The only folder which increased is the Windows folder itself. It tried the disk cleanup and it didn't helped.

Windows is eating my disk space? Why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I visualize the file system usage on Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/8248/how-can-i-visualize-the-file-system-usage-on-windows)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: All files together in C:\Windows\Temp have about 179 GB. C:\Windows\Logs\CBS has 13 GB. So what should I do?

Comment: Well you can delete everything (it'll let you) from C:\windows\temp, since it's a folder for holding *temp*orary files. :)

Comment: Thanks! Why isn't the disk cleanup tool showing me that?

Comment: Dunno, it usually does, but you may have to click "Clean up system files" first. as for the CBS logs, see this other SU question/answers: [Why is CBS.log file size 20 GB](http://superuser.com/questions/803842/why-is-cbs-log-file-size-20-gb)

Comment: Other related SU questions: [Emptying Windows temp folder is a good idea?](http://superuser.com/questions/418032/emptying-windows-temp-folder-is-a-good-idea), and [Can files in C:\WINDOWS\Temp be deleted and does Disk Cleanup do so?](http://superuser.com/questions/35257/can-files-in-c-windows-temp-be-deleted-and-does-disk-cleanup-do-so)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: Post your comments in a single answer and I mark them as expected.